# PHP rename fails but file_exists is true

Tags: php, rename, file-exists

I'm trying to rename all files in a folder, I want the last character before the extension to be removed.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblphotoseries WHERE photoSerieID = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($photoSerieID) . ' AND FKuID = ' . $_SESSION['uID'];
if($series = GetFromDB($sql)){
    foreach ($series as $serie){
        $path = '../uploads/' . $serie["FKcatID"] . '/' . $_SESSION['uCode'] .  '/' . $serie["seriesCode"] . '';
    }

    $files = scandir($path);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file != ".." && $file != "."){
            $new_name = explode(".", $file);
            $ext = $new_name[1];
            $new_name = $new_name[0];
            $new_name[strlen($new_name) - 1] = "";
            $new_name = $new_name . "." . $ext;
            $new_name = (string)$new_name;
            echo $file . " -> " . $new_name . "\n\r";
            clearstatcache();
            if(file_exists($path . '/' . $file)){
                echo "file_exists \n\r";
                clearstatcache();                   
                if(rename($path . '/' . $file, $path . '/' . $new_name)){
                    echo "rename successful \n\r";
                }else{
                    echo "rename failed \n\r";
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
AA04a_.jpg -> AA04a.jpg

file_exists 

rename failed 

AA04b_.png -> AA04b.png

file_exists 

rename failed 

AA04c_.png -> AA04c.png

file_exists 

rename failed
```

Can anyone spot what's going wrong here? Privileges are ok, I've tried chmod 0777 on the file before renaming as well, without success.

Thanks,
Rik

SOLVED:

```
$new_name[strlen($new_name) - 1] = "";
```

had to be replaced by

```
$new_name = substr_replace($new_name, '', strlen($new_name) - 1, 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure the user that is used to execute the PHP script is allowed to write in the folder ?

Comment: file_exists isn't very useful. you need to check `is_writeable()`. e.g. the file can exist, but you don't have the rights to modify it.

Comment: Did you check that your file isnt actually already there from a previous run or from another row in your SELECT with same name?

Comment: EricMORAND : yes, the underscore was added using rename.

MarcB : is_writeable() returns true

ToBe : I'm positive that the filename is unique ( i just checked using file_exists())

Comment: @Marc B he is checking the source file with file_exists, not the target file. So is_writable() is not usefull here. If I got this right?.

Comment: still need write permissions on the file to actually rename it, since a rename is changing the file's inode.

Comment: @MarcB: I already tried a chmod 0777 on the file that is to be renamed, I just tried it again. No luck.

Comment: need write rights on the folder it's in too.

Comment: @MarcB: folder permissions seem to be good as well, just set it to 0777. Which permissions change when a file is renamed? The underscore is added through rename() but I can't seem to get rid of it using rename(), the file stays in the same directory, only the filename changes.

Comment: I solved the problem, the problem was the following line:

   `$new_name[strlen($new_name) - 1] = "";`

I replaced it with
   `$new_name = substr_replace($new_name, '', strlen($new_name) - 1, 1);`

it works now. 
Thanks for your help guys!